# .animate executing twice only on Mac with magic mouse?

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I tested the code below on two seperate computers. One is windows with a normal mouse with normal scrolling and one is a MacBook Pro with a Magic Mouse with inherited Scrolling. Now the problem is, that on the windows pc this function works as it should and on MacBook it animates the same thing twice. It goes from let's say y = 0 to y = 250 and then instantly to 500, so obviously .animate is executing twice.

I tried to set a variable like `animationStarted = false`, and then set it to true once the main `else` block is reached and check this condition before running the animation. It didn't work. Another thing I tried was using `$(elem).clearQueue()`, but it also didn't work.

Does anyone have a suggestion, how I could make this work? I really don't know why it's executing twice

```
var currScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
var lastAnimation = 0;
var animationTime = 500; // in ms
var quietPeriod = 0; // in ms, time after animation to ignore mousescroll
$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e)
{
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // If the last mousescroll happened less that 100 ms ago, update
    // timeStamp and do nothing
    if (timeNow - lastAnimation < quietPeriod + animationTime) {
        return;
    } else {

        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 )
        {
            lastAnimation = new Date().getTime();
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: currScroll + 250}, animationTime, function()
                                    {
                                        currScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
                                    });
        }
        else if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0)
        {
            lastAnimation = new Date().getTime();
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: currScroll - 250}, animationTime, function()
                                    {
                                        currScroll = $('body').scrollTop();
                                    });
        }
    }



});
```

Comment: hmn maybe `$('body').stop(true,false)`

Comment: @johnSmith where should I put that code? Inside the else statement?

Comment: right before the `$('body').animate(` also keep in mind that values with touchpad or touch mouse may get negative when scrolling on top and get bigger than document.height when scrolling to bottom

Comment: @johnSmith sadly doesn't work :-/